# C#. WepApi для desktop программы (WPF или WinForms)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

Здравствуйте хотел спросить как организовать HTTP WepApi доступ к приложению на WPF.
Необходимо реализовать контроль состояния объекта (GET запросы от клиента) и  команды от клиента (POST).

хотелось бы чтото типа REST доступа

GET -  Получение состояния
host/lists/    - все объекты 
host/lists/10  - объект с id 10

POST - изменение по id
host/lists/10  -  заменить объект с id 10 на объект дессериализованный из тела запроса.

DELETE - удаление  по id
host/lists/10  -  удалить объект с id 10

Прошу поделиться best practices.
Давно пробовал HttpListener, вышло ли что-то альтернативное и более удобное?
Версия ПО (framework 4.5.2).
Заранее всем спасибо.

Comment: При чем тут WPF? Не понятно что вы пытаетесь сделать

Comment: Есть десктоп приложение. нужно к нему предоставить дотсуп по HTTP протоколу, предположим на чтение данных. HttpListener позволял это сделать хоть где, хоть в консоли

Comment: Имхо, `WPF`/`WinForm` - по большей части клиентские технологии. Сознавать на них сервер, это изврат... Если вы хотите управлять клиентами, то для таких целей используется `WCF`, либо на крайний случай поднимается `json-rpc` (или подобные аналоги).

Comment: для примера что бы я хотел: я использую RabbitMQ для межсервисного взаимодействия, недавно все windows машины перевел на EasyNetQ (обертка над RabbitMQ). Может есть чо-то удобное и для WebApi

Comment: RPC могу и RabbitMQ. интересует простой webAPI.

Comment: То-есть я так понял если хочу извратится то использовать HttpListener?

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать HttpClient, отправлять POST и GET запросы (и не только) из приложения, и обрабатывать полученные данные. Так же можно добавлять заголовки к запросам.

Пример запроса:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(APP_PATH + "/api/Account/Register", registerModel).Result;
    return response.StatusCode.ToString();
}
```

Ссылки по теме: [Создание десктопного клиента на C# для Web API](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet_webapi/5.3.php), [Сonsole WebApiClient](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/console-webapiclient)

Comment: Вы мне расписали клиента а мне нужен сервер

Comment: HttpListener из той-же сборки